# Conversão Date to String em Pyhton

Tags: mysql, python

Estou tentando pegar uma data desse seguinte select no python

```
select MAX(PAYMENT_DATE) from fact_cashflow
WHERE DOCUMENT_ID = 'SALDO FINAL' and PAYMENT_AMOUNT > 0
```

Porém a minha resposta no console é  essa

> (datetime.date(2017, 2, 1),)

Gostaria que a data viesse formatada em 
'2017-02-01'

Como faço?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A função [date_format](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp) permite formatar a data retornada na consulta do banco Mysql:

```
select date_format(MAX(PAYMENT_DATE), '%Y-%m-%d') from fact_cashflow
WHERE DOCUMENT_ID = 'SALDO FINAL' and PAYMENT_AMOUNT > 0;
```

Comment: Muito  Obrigado, consegui por aqui.

Comment: O melhor quase sempre é deixar o Python ler um objeto datetime do banco - e transformar de datetime para string com o método `strftime` apenas no ponto da aplicação que gera a saída para o usuário. Um objeto datetime é muito mais útil dentro da ĺógica do programa.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar o `.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`

Desta forma:

```
t = datetime.date(2017, 2, 1)
t.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Sua resposta será:
    '2017-02-01'

Comment: Esta é a forma correta: converter a data na hora de apresetnta-la parao usuário em Python. Na resposta aceita, o que vem do banco é uma string, e se perdem toda as vantagens de objetos datetime do Python: comparações, distancia para outras datas, poder ser usada novamente em outro objeto, etc...